# wheelchart and danish letter æ ø å

Tags: tikz-pic

Why can't I get the danish letter æ, ø, å ind the names in my wheelchart
I want to write Mængder but it will not work for me.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                   % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet (UTF8)
\usepackage[danish]{babel}                  % Dokumentets sprog
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz,wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.text}
\usepackage {siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns}


\gdef\exampleforthismanual{%
    14/Apricot/Opsamling/,
    40/LimeGreen/Mængder/,
    20/Melon/Funktioner/%
}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=-60:180, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{\exampleforthismanual} 
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=180:360, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        16/Peach/Eksponentielle og logaritmefunktioner/
    }
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=,arc data style={text color=white},, domain=360:450, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        50/Plum/Potensfunktioner/
    }
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=450:540, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        50/WildStrawberry/Vektorer/
    }    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It will most likely work if you remove `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.

Comment: with utf8 it works if you add a brace: M{æ}ngder.

Comment: Thank you very much @UlrikeFischer

Comment: And thank you @Marijn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previously noted by Marijn and Ulrike Fischer and in the answer by Mico, the code in the question works if `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is removed and `Mængder` is replaced by `M{æ}ngder` (note the braces around æ).

It is unnecessary to use a `\wheelchart` 4 times. All slices can be drawn with a single `\wheelchart`. For this, the key `value=1` is removed. Instead, the first value for each slice is used for the key `value`.

The option `text color=white` is only passed to the fifth slice with the key `arc data style{5}`.

In the question, the code for each slice had a `/` 4 times. The last `/` can be removed.

The package `wheelchart` (which I wrote) loads the package `tikz` so `\usepackage{tikz}` was removed. Also `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}`, `\usepackage{siunitx}` and `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}` are unnecessary for this MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=\WCvarC,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style{5}={text color=white},
  data=,
  domain=-60:540,
  inner plot={
    {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
    {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)}
  },
  outer plot={
    {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
    {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)}
  }
]{%
  80/Apricot/Opsamling,
  80/LimeGreen/M{æ}ngder,
  80/Melon/Funktioner,
  180/Peach/Eksponentielle og logaritmiske funktioner,
  90/Plum/Potensfunktioner,
  90/WildStrawberry/Vektorer%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX -- both are natively unicode/utf8-aware -- to compile your document. (If you simply must use pdfLaTeX, be sure to employ the suggestion @UlrikeFischer has posted in a comment.) I used LuaLaTeX to generate the following output.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[dvipsnames,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex 
   %%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   %% And be sure to employ Ulrike Fischer's suggestion
   %% (e.g., 'M{æ}ngder' instead of 'Mængder')
\else
   \usepackage{unicode-math} % load 'fontspec' automatically
\fi

\usepackage[danish]{babel}  % Dokumentets sprog
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz,wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns}

\gdef\exampleforthismanual{%
    14/Apricot/Opsamling/,
    40/LimeGreen/Mængder/, % <-- write 'M{æ}ngder' for pdfLaTeX
    20/Melon/Funktioner/%
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=-60:180, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{\exampleforthismanual} 
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=180:360, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        16/Peach/Eksponentielle og logaritmefunktioner/
    }
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=,arc data style={text color=white},, domain=360:450, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        50/Plum/Potensfunktioner/
    }
    \wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarC, arc data pos=0.5, data=, domain=450:540, inner plot={
        {int((#1)/180)*5+(0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    outer plot={ {int((#1)/180)*5+(-0.5-((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*2.5)*cos(#1)},
        {(2.5+((-1)^Mod(int((#1)/180),2))*0.5)*sin(#1)} },
    value=1 ]{
        50/WildStrawberry/Vektorer/
    }    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```